# IEXCloud "change percent" statistics make no sense

Tags: api, stock

The results of stats calls to IEX Cloud make no sense.

Docs are at https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#stats-basic but they don't go into the details. Just saying a field exists seems to be enough for them.

Here is a result for today for Agilent from an API call:

```
{"companyName":"Agilent Technologies Inc.","marketcap":48702022828,"week52high":179.35,"week52low":104.59,"week52highSplitAdjustOnly":179.57,"week52lowSplitAdjustOnly":105.19,"week52change":0.4686617632157193,"sharesOutstanding":302722668,"float":0,"avg10Volume":1289493,"avg30Volume":1291085,"day200MovingAvg":152.69,"day50MovingAvg":156.41,"employees":16400,"ttmEPS":3.21,"ttmDividendRate":0.7744734957186514,"dividendYield":0.004813982444795198,"nextDividendDate":"","exDividendDate":"2021-10-04","nextEarningsDate":"2021-11-22","peRatio":49.19396245236364,"beta":0.9917301080890041,"maxChangePercent":6.000809392433486,"year5ChangePercent":2.617394432702253,"year2ChangePercent":1.1149775855495814,"year1ChangePercent":0.4686617632157193,"ytdChangePercent":0.3655365001761244,"month6ChangePercent":0.2405176122966075,"month3ChangePercent":0.011620302832134222,"month1ChangePercent":0.0709625882039675,"day30ChangePercent":0.05432859296153092,"day5ChangePercent":0.028578735374976016}
```

For example "year5ChangePercent" with value 2.617. Agilent is up roughly 400% in the last 5 years, from about $44 to $160. So how on earth did they come up with 2.617?